# Trying to replace a word within a cstring

Tags: c++, cstring, strstr

I'm quite stuck at this point. Ultimately I want to send `sentence` to `replaceSubstring` then return the same sentence with "the" replaced with "that". I know I should be using pointers, but I'm not sure where and why exactly. Any advice?

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Ch12_08.cpp: In function ‘char replaceSubstring(char*, char*, char*)’:
Ch12_08.cpp:16: error: request for member ‘strstr’ in ‘sent’, which is of non-class type ‘char*’
Ch12_08.cpp:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’
Ch12_08.cpp:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’
Ch12_08.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Ch12_08.cpp:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
```

Here's the code I'm working with..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // Needed for strstr to work

using namespace std;

char replaceSubstring(char sent[], char oldW[], char newW[]){
    char *strPtr = NULL;

    strPtr = &sent.strstr(sent, oldW);
    *strPtr = newW;
    return sent;
}

int main()
{
    char sentence[35] = "the dog jumped over the fence";
    char oldWord[5] = "the";
    char newWord[6] = "that";
    char newSentence[35] = {NULL};

    wcout << "The original sentence is: " << sentence << endl;

    newSentence[] = replaceSubstring(sentence, oldWord, newWord);


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong:  `strstr` is not a member function of `char *`.  `char *` is not a class type.

Rather, `strstr` is just a plain function.  This will probably work better for you:

```
strPtr = strstr(sent, oldW);
```

Once you've found where `oldW` is in `strPtr`, you will need to copy `newW` over `oldW`.  If `newW` and `oldW` are the same length that shouldn't be difficult.  If they might be different lengths (as they seem to be in your example), you have your work cut out for you.

In any case, the line you have after `strstr` will not do what you want.  You need a loop to copy characters, or similar.

And finally, you can't return a character array from your function like that.  You need to pass `newSentence` as an argument to the function if you want your function to fill that array.

Part of me wonders why you're even trying this with C strings when `std::string` makes this so much nicer...

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's for a class. I wonder why as well though.. I don't mind the extra insight though. It just seems almost counterintuitive to the rest of the stuff we've been learning.

Comment: BTW, are you supposed to replace _all_ instances of `oldW` with `newW` or just the first?  The answer to that question changes the work you need to do.